# Segregate user home folders when both users are members of `staff` group

Tags: permission, user-account

I want to segregate two home folders, `/Users/justin` and `/Users/anotherUser` such that one user cannot view the contents of the other.

My first attempt was to change the permissions of group `everyone` for `/Users/justin` from "Read only" (default) to "No Access", and similarly for "anotherUser".

[image: after changing permissions of /Users/justin]

But "anotherUser" can still read the contents of `/Users/justin`. I think this is because both users are members of the `staff` group.

```
➜  /Users ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  15 root     wheel   480  2 May 09:51 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 altuser  staff   448 20 Jun 13:24 altuser
drwxr-x---@ 86 justin   staff  2752 20 Jun 17:56 justin
```

My understanding is that by default, macOS assigns all users to `staff`.

How can I segregate the two home folders without removing them from `staff`? Or is it safe to remove them from `staff`?

Comment: Please add Terminal output **as text** by copy/pasting from Terminal, it's much easier to read that way.

Comment: On my Macs, admin users can see a list of the folders inside another user's accounts, but the folders have a 'No entry' sign and cannot be accessed (without modifying the permissions, which, as has been said, can be done by any admin user).

Comment: Are you removing both users from admin group? If not, they can grant themselves access to any folder that’s not encrypted with a separate key on the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, almost all the top-level contents of a user folder should already be set this way - they have no group, only owner & everyone. Owner is r/w, everyone is no access.

[image]

---

[image]

Just remove the group entirely to restore to defaults.

[image]

Of course, as already mentioned - any other admin can undo this. You have no powers as admin that don't also belong to every other admin.

Comment: I couldn't remove it via UI. macOS gave me `The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission` but `chmod 700` worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove read access for `staff` from the home directory by <strike>setting it to "No Access" in the Sharing & Permission box (your first screenshot)</strike> removing the `staff` entry (or by running `sudo chmod 700 justin altuser` in Terminal).

PS: This assumes that neither user is an admin user (because admin users can obviously change it back easily).

Comment: Thanks. There isn't a "No Access" option for staff group, only read/write, read-only, and "Write only (Drop Box)" (sic). I just removed `staff` entirely as suggested by Tetsujin. `chmod` would work too.

Comment: @Justin So much for testing an answer before posting it. Indeed, setting it to 0700 removes the staff group in the Info window (but shows everyone as "No Access").